# Add new column from custom table to magento 2 customer grid

Tags: magento2, customer-grid

I'm using magento v2.2.5 and i have a custom table that one of the column i need to show in magento 2 grid customer column, my custom table look like this:

```
##membership##
+-----------------+-----------+-------+-------------+
|membership_id     |customer_id|status |requested_at|
+------------------+-----------+-------+------------+
|        1         |     1     |   1   | 2018-11-01 |
|        2         |     2     |   0   | 2018-11-03 |
|        3         |     4     |   2   | 2018-11-04 |
|        4         |     6     |   1   | 2018-11-05 |
+------------------+-----------+-------+------------+
```

i need to show the status column, above in magento 2 customer grid, how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it Adding Column to the Customer_grid_flat

you need to define the column under etc\ and than in DB need to set the 
'is_used_in_grid' => true,
'is_visible_in_grid' => true,

against the custom column